# C# Code Repeating User Input Prompt After Calling Method

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm trying to make a program that asks for user inputs and then gives the option of restarting if the user chooses that they are unhappy with their choices. The program works perfectly if they select options and then choose yes at the end however if they choose No, select attributes again, and then select Yes the user is prompted to choose if they accept again. The program reads:

There are your attribute points!

Do you accept these? Type 1 for Yes, Type 2 for No. If No you can choose again:

1

Do you accept these? Type 1 for Yes, Type 2 for No. If No you can choose again:

1

Press any key to continue...

Here is the code:

```
       while (true)
        {

            Console.Write("Do you accept these? Type 1 for Yes, Type 2 for No. If No you can choose again:  ");
            areYouHappyWithChoices = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!UInt32.TryParse(areYouHappyWithChoices, out validChoices))
                Console.WriteLine("Please try again. Enter 1 for Yes and 2 for No");
            else if (validChoices > 2 || validChoices < 1)
                Console.WriteLine("Please try again. Enter 1 for Yes and 2 for No");
            else if (areYouHappyWithChoices == "2")
                chooseAttributePoints(); //this method contains the whole routine
            else
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Well this solution is overcomplicating it a bit don't you think? Why don't you just do:                                                                                                                   `if (areYouHappyWithChoices == "1") break;                                                 else if (areYouHappyWithChoices == "2") chooseAttributePoints();`? Or you the while loop could even check `while (areYouHappyWithChoices != "1")`

Comment: Your code works just fine. Could you please explain in more detail what you think doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: Yes, sorry my codes a little clunky. I started coding ~2 weeks ago and am just working out how to string the basics together. Next up will be streamlining it a bit lol. As for the error, I'm getting prompted to choose yes or no twice if I choose No once and reenter values. Basically if I reenter values, and I press 1 for yes Im ok with these, I get asked again to enter 1 or 2 before the program completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tested your code and it worked for me just fine. It seems that you have an additional `Console.ReadLine()` in your `chooseAttributePoints()` method and therefore you have to enter your choice twice after calling  `chooseAttributePoints()`. Please check that to make sure this is the problem.

**Remarks:**

I also restructured your code a bit, so it is more readable and has less redundancies.

```
int validChoices;
do
{
  Console.WriteLine("do some logic ......"); // replace this line with your chooseAttributePoints() method ...

  Console.Write("Do you accept these? Type 1 for Yes, Type 2 for No. If No you can choose again:  ");

  // read input until user gets it right and enters a valid number ...
  var areYouHappyWithChoices = Console.ReadLine();
  while (!int.TryParse(areYouHappyWithChoices, out validChoices) || validChoices < 1 || validChoices > 2)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Please try again. Enter 1 for Yes and 2 for No");
    areYouHappyWithChoices = Console.ReadLine();
  }
} while (validChoices != 1);
```

Comment: Thank you. I added a Console.Writeline before the break like this:                 else
    Console.WriteLine("We may now begin the game!");
    break;  which seems to be preventing the code from asking for user input twice

Comment: Thank you for the simplified code. I gave it a go and hit a handful of snags . The basic code works for now however I'll make a note of the simplified version and as i get a bit better at this will loop back on this to streamline things. Thanks all!